# How do I use QDesktopServices::openUrl with 'file:' URL containing '#'?

Tags: qt, qurl, qdesktopservices

In my application, I generate a HTML file that I want to open by clicking on a button.
So my file is named, for example:

```
QString file = "F:/the_path/to_the_/generated_html_file.html";
```

On Windows I change it to:

```
file = "file:///F:/the_path/to_the_/generated_html_file.html";
```

so that I can open it with :

```
QDesktopServices::openUrl(QUrl(file));
```

and it opens in the default browser.

But when the character `#` is present in the path or file name, it doesn't work any more and it seems that the URL is truncated just after the `#`.

For example, if I name the file `generated#_html_file.html`, I get this error message:

```
ShellExecute 'F:/the_path/to_the_/generated' failed (error 2).
```

Why does that happen, and how can I avoid it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In a URL, `#` is a character that delimits the 'fragment identifier' from the resource location.  To reference a `file:` URL with a literal `#`, it needs to be escaped (as `%23`).

Reference: RFC 1738:

> The character
>   "#" is unsafe and should    always be encoded because it is used in
>   World Wide Web and in other    systems to delimit a URL from a
>   fragment/anchor identifier that might    follow it.

As noted by [SteveTJS](/users/1921299), the static method `QUrl::fromLocalFile()` is provided for this purpose, so you can write

```c++
QDesktopServices::openUrl(QUrl::fromLocalFile(file));
```

instead of

```c++
QDesktopServices::openUrl(QUrl(file));
```

This will

1. Prepend the `file:` protocol identifier and `//` empty hostname
2. Convert native path separator to `/` (if different)
3. Encode any non-safe characters for URL.

Comment: Indeed, I posted my answer at the same time. The function QUrl::fromLocalFile(...) does the work.

Comment: @Steve - quite right, I don't use `QUrl` very much, so I'd forgotten that.  I've upvoted your answer, and will add a note to mine.

Answer (score 6):

I just found the solution:

```
QString file = "F:/the_path/to_the_/generated#_html_file.html";
QUrl url = QUrl::fromLocalFile(file);
// gives url="file:///F:/the_path/to_the_/generated%23_html_file.html";
QDesktopServices::openUrl(url); //works
```

Comment: Ah yes - `fromLocalFile()` is there for exactly this kind of conversion.  No need for the `QUrl(url)` copy, though?

Comment: @TobySpeight No need in QUrl(url) since the url parameter is already good.